# Babel output in bundle.js file not properly outputting

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have been trying for hours to figure out what is going on with Babel.  It is not outputting anything close to what it should.

Shown here: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=G4QwTgBAdiC2CmAhArgSwDYBN6QLwQDNkoBjAF1QHsoAKA1MAZzIDk55cAiAKUoAsonADQR0IZmwRcAIpXicAlBADeAKBLVGldPAB06SgHM6DCewgBqCJ2uXR41uwUBuVQF9XqmAhQZsYGhcgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=

I can provide any context/files that you may need to deduce a solution.  Thanks.

sample script.js function:

```
var nameBuilder = function(firstName="John", lastName="Doe") {
console.log(firstName + " " + lastName);
};

nameBuilder();
```

Babel output (came in one block of code so I did not indent):

!function(e){var n={};function t(o){if(n[o])return n[o].exports;var r=n[o]={i:o,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[o].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,t),r.l=!0,r.exports}t.m=e,t.c=n,t.d=function(e,n,o){t.o(e,n)||Object.defineProperty(e,n,{configurable:!1,enumerable:!0,get:o})},t.r=function(e){Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},t.n=function(e){var n=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return t.d(n,"a",n),n},t.o=function(e,n){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,n)},t.p="",t(t.s=1)}([function(e,n,t){"use strict";!function(){var e=arguments.length>0&&void 0!==arguments[0]?arguments[0]:"John",n=arguments.length>1&&void 0!==arguments[1]?arguments[1]:"Doe";console.log(e+" "+n)}()},function(e,n,t){e.exports=t(0)}]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not incorrect, Babel is a traspiler that enables programmers to use newer JavaScript features (like the default parameters in your example) on platforms that may not have implemented them yet.  In this example, Babel has rewritten your function to replace `undefined` with your default parameter in order to work with platforms that have not implemented default parameters yet.

for reference, here is the compatibility table:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I guess my question now is why is the result on their website different than what I got by running it through webpack?  If the script.js function was for example "const year = 2018;" it should just change it to a var, but it output something very similar to the above output.

Comment: I would check your configuration, your output above appears to be minified (unnecessary characters removed).  There are flags you can set to control this behavior.  One more thing that babel is doing here is that it's wrapping it inside of an IIFE and exporting it as a module (likely for portability reasons)

Comment: Would I have to access the configuration through a .babelrc file?  Or is there a dedicated place I can view the configuration and manipulate it?

Comment: The two most common methods are with the .babelrc file and through the JS API (which allows for a config parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Look like there is some compression / uglify flag set, which is often used to reduce size of production code.
Check your flags / configuration / default behaviour of babel.

Comment: If I had the script.js as something like "const year = 2018;"  should I be getting an output near what the above shows?  Does that signify a deeper issue?

Comment: As Shimsh said, check your configuration.
You also mention that the output posted is from webpack, so that configuration would be interesting as well.

Overall I don't see an issue, it's minified code.
Try to run it.

Comment: I ran it in the browser and it appeared that things checked out.  I am curious as to why it would be minified as I just went through default installation paths.  How would you recommend I access the configuration?

Comment: yes.
If there are also mapping files for the source, it's not a problem.
Otherwise, minified code without mapping files makes debugging in the browser very hard.